# I want to change the speed of ABB IRB2400 in rviz by varying state_display_time property using cpp code ?How can i do this?

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, abb, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a function to be included in my cpp code to change stste_display_time when neeeded.

---

Edit: Is it possible to change the speed of manipulation in RVIZ (ROS Indigo) ?  I am using an ABB Robot manipulator and I would like to very the speed of manipulation. One way I found is by varying state_display_time using changedstatedisplaytime() function. But in my understanding state_display_time variable is only available up to Groovy, Is that right?  Can anybody have any alternate way of solving this problem. Thanking you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222361/i-want-to-change-the-speed-of-abb-irb2400-in-rviz-by-varying-state_display_time-property-using-cpp-code-?how-can-i-do-this?/) by [sooraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/25307/sooraj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-21**:
Please do not post *answers* if you want to update your question. ROS Answers is not a regular forum (where you can post multiple times). I've moved your update to your question, but in the future, please *edit* your question using the *edit* link/button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it is not possible to change state display time variable  in  indigo version .

---

Originally posted by [alexi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24636/alexi/) with karma: 38 on 2015-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0